# Parsing of GC log file using python

Tags: python, regex

I am new to python . Learning Python so that i can create some tools to help me in daily tasks.

I have a log file which gives the heap memory details at certain time stamp .

e.g.

```
####<2020/04/21 00:00:00.977 +0200> <XYZ> <123> <141><INFO><guest> <XXX.technical.performance.memory.diagnostics> <traceId: "", spanId: "" backSessionId: "", jsessionid: ""> $<Memory load: type=diagnostics; freememory-heap=1131750664 (1G 55M 329k 264 bytes) (48.63%); freememory-young=488244928 (465M 641k 704 bytes) (68.12%); freememory-tenured=643505736 (613M 711k 584 bytes) (39.95%);. Metrics [name=free_memory, value=1079; name=free_tenuredgen_memory, value=613; ].
```

I want fetch details like this and write to csv for multiple lines ,

*Timestamp=00:00:00.977 , Freememory-heap= 1131750664 ,freememory-young=488244928,  freememory-tenured=643505736*

Can anybody suggest me how to write basic code to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good task for regexp usage, you can retrieve this information like this:

```
import re

regex = r"(?P<timestamp>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}).*" \
        r"freememory-heap=(?P<frequency_heap>\d+).*" \
        r"freememory-young=(?P<frequency_young>\d+).*" \
        r"freememory-tenured=(?P<frequency_tenured>\d+)"

test_str = "####<2020/04/21 00:00:00.977 +0200> <XYZ> <123> <141> <INFO> <guest> <XXX.technical.performance.memory.diagnostics> <traceId: \"\", spanId: \"\" backSessionId: \"\", jsessionid: \"\"> $<Memory load: type=diagnostics; freememory-heap=1131750664 (1G 55M 329k 264 bytes) (48.63%); freememory-young=488244928 (465M 641k 704 bytes) (68.12%); freememory-tenured=643505736 (613M 711k 584 bytes) (39.95%);. Metrics [name=free_memory, value=1079; name=free_tenuredgen_memory, value=613; ]."

matches = re.findall(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
print(matches)
# [('00:00:00.977', '1131750664', '488244928', '643505736')]
```

Comment: Thanks for the this code !! This works completely fine for my case .